# What is the dimension of $\{Y\in M_n(\Bbb C); \exists\ X\in M_n(\Bbb C) | AX=Y\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> What is the dimension of $U=\{Y\in M_n(\Bbb C); \exists\ X\in M_n(\Bbb C) | AX=Y\}$.
> Here, $A$ is a matrix in $M_n(\Bbb C)$, the $n\times n$ complex matrices. $\operatorname{rank} A=r$.

Clearly, the columns of $Y$ are all in $L(\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n)$, where $\beta_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Let $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r$ be the maximal linearly independent vectors. Then $U$ has a base $(\gamma_1,\cdots,\gamma_n)$, where $\gamma_i\in \{\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r\}$. So the dimension of $U$ is $r^n$? But $\dim M_n(\Bbb C)=n^2$.

Comment: Is not the image of $A\in {\bf C}^{n\times n}$ the subspace here? Since ${\rm im}(A)=\{Y\in {\bf C}^{n}\colon \exists  X\in {\bf C}^{n}\colon AX=Y\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is $nr$ as we can write $Y = \sum_{i=1}^r b_{1i} [\beta_i,0,...,0] + \sum_{i=1}^r b_{2i} [0,\beta_i,...,0] + ... + \sum_{i=1}^r b_{ni} [0,0,...,\beta_i]$

All of these are linearly independent since $\beta_1,...\beta_r$ are linearly independent and they span $U$.